# redux form v6, Unknown props message

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I'm trying to do simple form rendering but I always get this error

`` Unknown props `input`, `meta` on <input> tag. ``

I've researched this question before and haven't found anything except the github discussions, which literally throw around 4 or 5 different implementations of how it should be done with no consensus, and I also followed the v6 docs' implementation this way, but to no avail. any suggestions?

I'm using v6.2.0, the latest version at the time of me posting this.

I am directly copy pasting from the example here, http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.15/examples/syncValidation/, still get an error. (I attached their code below)

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

const validate = values => {
  const errors = {}
  if (!values.username) {
    errors.username = 'Required'
  } else if (values.username.length > 15) {
    errors.username = 'Must be 15 characters or less'
  }
  if (!values.email) {
    errors.email = 'Required'
  } else if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email)) {
    errors.email = 'Invalid email address'
  }
  if (!values.age) {
    errors.age = 'Required'
  } else if (isNaN(Number(values.age))) {
    errors.age = 'Must be a number'
  } else if (Number(values.age) < 18) {
    errors.age = 'Sorry, you must be at least 18 years old'
  }
  return errors
}

const renderField = props => (
  <div>
    <label>{props.placeholder}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...props}/>
      {props.touched && props.error && <span>{props.error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
)

const SyncValidationForm = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field name="username" type="text" component={renderField} placeholder="Username"/>
      <Field name="email" type="email" component={renderField} placeholder="Email"/>
      <Field name="age" type="number" component={renderField} placeholder="Age"/>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
        <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>Clear Values</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'syncValidation',  // a unique identifier for this form
  validate                 // <--- validation function given to redux-form
})(SyncValidationForm)
```

Comment: console.log(this.props); at the top of your render and post the result

Comment: Object {anyTouched: false, asyncValidating: false, dirty: false, error: undefined, form: "syncValidation"…}

Comment: i also tried <input {...props.input} /> but this registers no changes in the input (can't see what you're typing) and no error or validation checking occurs

Comment: @LarryStraw check out my answer. It will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using the code example of `6.0.0-alpha.15` version.

Implementing [`6.2.0` example](http://redux-form.com/6.2.0/examples/simple/) should fix the errors (*in case you're using redux-form v6.2.0*).

[Credits](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2132).